# Switching power sources with a FET while avoiding brownouts

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switches

I've got a power bank powering a SBC with 5V, and I want to be able to power this SBC with 5V to not waste batteries. The SBC in question consumes around 500mA, with peaks up to 1A - so diodes are out of question. How do I make 5V source switching circuit which would prefer the external input (thus detaching the power bank's input), would be capable of switching the said load and not cause brownouts in the process (that excludes relay-based circuits)? I am familiar with MOSFETs but I don't yet understand the thing well enough to make sure it'll work correctly with body diodes. Also, would it be possible to base the circuit around really basic components? It's not that simple for me to buy specialised ICs, but I do have access to simple MOSFETs and such.

Comment: SBC means what?

Comment: @Andyaka Single Board Computer

Comment: Yeah, think of it like a Raspberry Pi (it is, I just want to make sure the question doesn't suddenly migrate ;-) )

Comment: What's the tolerance on the 5V?

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to say that diodes are out of the question.  Two Schottky diodes seem like exactly what you want, although they should be inside the regulator feedback path so that their voltage drop is compensated for automatically.

Another option is to make this "power bank" (whatever that really is) put out a bit above 5 V, and then have a power supply that puts out even more.  Both these feed the input of a buck switcher that makes the regulated 5 V for the computer.

The buck switcher will automatically adjust to whatever input voltage it is given.  With the power supply having the higher voltage, like 12 V for example, and this "power bank" maybe 9 V, the power supply will always be providing the power when it is on.

### Added after "power bank" defined

You now say this "power bank" is something you made that contains batteries and a regulator to keep the output steady.  You should fix your question to define this.  "Power bank" by itself is ambiguous.

The conceptually simple answer is to have the power supply and the power bank feed the input to a 5 V buck switcher, each thru its own Schottky diode.  Adjust the power bank voltage to be a little above 5 V after the diode, like maybe 6 V.  Now the power supply only needs to result in higher voltage after its diode than the power bank does, and the power will be taken from it instead of the power bank.  With a buck regulator, there is a wide range of voltage this power supply can have.  Just about any 5 V buck regulator you can find will work with at least 12 V in.  That's a common power supply voltage, so there will be many readily available alternatives.  9 V will also work fine, for example, assuming the power pack puts out less than that.

A better approach is to step back and look at the whole problem.  You want to run your 5 V device from a power supply when available, but from batteries when not.  Therefore build one device that does that.  Only a single switching regulator is needed, unlike the two with one in the battery bank and the other to make the final 5 V.  Use a single 5 V buck switcher, with diodes to get its input directly from the batteries or the power supply, whichever has the higher voltage.

Put the batteries in series so that the lowest voltage is always above the desired 5 V output.  Choose a power supply with higher voltage than the highest battery pack voltage.  Use a microcontroller to shut down the batteries when they get too low.

For extra credit, charge the batteries when the power supply voltage is present.  This again would be managed by the micro, which would also do the charge balancing.

Basically, this will be a 5 V UPS.

Comment: Not all "power banks" are created equal. Some of them have crappy regulation and will put out 5V only when there is no load. The crappy ones have an output voltage that goes down with amount of load current. I've tested one of the bad ones that goes down to 4.7V when the rated 2A load is placed on it. The better ones will hold the 5V output until the load exceeds the rated output current.

Comment: I'm actually using a self-built powerbank with 18650 and a DC-DC attached, but the 9V is out of question - I'm making it USB-compliant, and I'm sure there has to be a way to do this switching.

Comment: Hmm. The DC-DC I'm using is a XL6009 one, and it has a Schottky in the circuit. Could the feedback path suddenly get messed up because there's slightly another voltage on the input?

Answer (score 2):

The simple scheme with reversed single MOSFET works perfect. All power lines may have 5V, because voltage dropping on Schottky and body-diode are differ.
[image: 1 MOSFET]

The Raspberry Pi can consumes 2.5A with peripheral devicies. So, use MOSFET with batteries for reducing energy losses.

Comment: I'm actually using this circuit when top source is 5V, bottom is Li-ion battery (3-4V) and it works great =) I didn't pick it because of diode losses while it is using top power source, which ain't cool. I'm thinking of improving upon it though.
Note: I never encountered 2.5A on a Raspberry, this has to be a really heavily-loaded setup, honestly =)
Но спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it without diodes and their attendant losses: 
[image]

I've chosen R1C1 so that +5 is up and stable before the relay switches, and chosen C2 so that the voltage to R2 (the load) doesn't droop below 4.5 volts  during switching from battery to +5 supply.

Unfortunately, While my circuit works well for switching from the battery to the 5V supply, it doesn't work at all well when switching from the +5 supply to the battery.

The reason is that since the relay has a large amount of hysteresis between MUST MAKE and MUST BREAK, the relay will stay made until the supply voltage drops enough for the relay to kick out, and that variation in power supply voltage will be presented to the load as well as to the relay coil.

I don't think there's any way around the hysteresis problem using MOSFETS and just RCs  either, since there'll be some voltage variation on their gates between ON and OFF, and unless you get through that threshold quickly enough, your load's going to suffer.

I think the switching can be done quickly enough using a voltage comparator to set the switching threshold voltage, so, back to the drawing board...

Comment: A relay wastes power.

Comment: @laptop2d: Not power which affects the load in any way, though, so it's not **wasting** power, it's **using** power to achieve that goal.

Comment: I've done this type of power source switching with a relay before, and it caused brownouts. The reason is that a relay had a huge switching time compared to the circuit consumption, and it would brown out no matter what. I'm sure the situation is going to be the same no matter the relay - the capacitor needed is really big, and that's not viable for my application when I know FET-based solutions are free from this drawback, and it's crucial for me to avoid brownouts because of FS corruptions.

Comment: I'm considering a make-before-break relay though, if I find a good&accessible one.

Comment: @АрсенийПичугин:I don''t understand what you mean by "huge switching time compared to the circuit consumption" and by "FS corruption"

 Unfortunately, while my circuit works well for switching from the battery to the 5V supply, it doesn't work at all well when switching from the +5 supply to the battery.

The reason is since the relay has a large amount of hysteresis between MUST MAKE and MUST BREAK, the relay will stay made until the supply voltage drops enough for the relay to kick out, and that variation in power supply voltage will be presented to the load as well as to the relay coil.